# Del siguiente codigo, como puedo meter un for y u while? (trinket)

Tags: python

```
for i in range(2):
  print ("Hello")

import random

def game():
  x = int(raw_input("Give me a number"))
  z = random.randint(1,10)
  if x==z:
    print "you won"
  else:
    print "I´am sorry the winning number is", z
    return;

def result():
  while game()<11:
    print "that statement is true"
    return;

game()
result()
```

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta carece de la informacion necesaria para que alguno de nosotros pueda ayudarte. Por favor consulta la [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorarla.

Comment: Hola, soy muy muy nuevo en el mundo de la programación (I´taking baby steps). de ese código en trinket me gustaría que la pregunta se repitiera hasta que el usuario gane. Ocupo agregar un While & For como parte de una tarea pero realmente no se como hacerlo. espero ayude.

Comment: bueno, todo eso que estas explicando en el comentario deberia estar en la pregunta.. y sabe que aqui no hacemos las tareas de otro, si no que ayudamos con problemas especificos. si te dijera donde poner el while te estaria terminando el ejercicio. como te gustaria que te ayudaramos sin darte la solucion al ejercicio?

Comment: Ah entiendo...Muchas Gracias lo tomare en cuenta en caso de futuras preguntas, mi propósito es el mismo. Quiero aprender, es algo que me ha gustado mucho aun así la lógica me cuenta mucho. Como quiero que me ayuden?: Se lo que quiero es que repita hasta que el usuario obtenga la respuesta correcta como parte del Juego, pero no si ponerlo dentro de la función y antes de que?. Un pequeño hint ayudaría, no estoy pidiendo la respuesta mas que una pequeña ayuda. He tratado de todo afuera, adentro. usando for and While. esto apenas lo vi la semana pasada. he tratado de hacer otra función pero nada.

Comment: interpretando un poco el código que colocas puedo concluir que quieres hacer que el jugador haga 10 intentos y luego termine el juego, de ser esto correcto lo que tienes es que cambiar un poco la lógica [acá te dejo un ejemplol](https://goo.gl/suQzZY)

Answer (score 1):

Analicemos tu codigo y veamos los problemas:

hay un for perdido por alla arriba.. imprime hello dos veces..

despues defines dos funciones:

```
game()
result()
```

y despues haces una llamada a `game()`

`game()` devuelve.. nada.... internamente `game()` pide un numero, lo compara con el calculado, avisa si ganaste o no, y vuelve...

después `result()` no hace mas que lió, porque vuelve a llamar a `game()` y se fija si lo que se regresa (que es nada, porque el return en game esta vació) es menor que 11. y por eso da true....

Ahora... pensemos.. si lo que queres es que se repita `game()` hasta que ganes.. no deberias ejecutar `game()` hasta que efectivamente ganes?? y como hariamos eso.. tal vez si `game()` nos devolviera si ganaste o no... y eso se ejecutara hasta que fuera true...

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda voy a tratar.

Comment: si la respuesta te sirvio y es valida aceptala.. si no, comenta despues que mas podemos hacer para ayudarte...